# How does the JVM utilization work in Snowflake?

Tags: api, jvm, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I use Snowflake(Standard edition) as a data warehouse and have created 6 warehouses. There is an API job crashing often causing memory issue(Java Heap error) leading to other jobs failing. I want to understand the role of JVM here and what can be done to save other jobs from failing?

Comment: Can you provide more details please?

Comment: Is that memory issue from the client side (the API) ?

Comment: I am not sure which side the issue lies, but my guess is it is Snowflake. The data was loading into the Snowflake from the client API and then it failed as Java Heap error, so the API job was done but there was no sufficient computing memory left for other jobs and most of the job failed because of no memory available for computation.

I understand that Snowflake takes care DBA side but is there any way I can avoid this situation in future?